# Seeking World Land Cover data

Tags: data, land-cover

I need to get land cover data for the entire world. I'm using corine land cover data for Europe:

http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/clc-2006-vector-data-version-2

but I have no idea how to get data for the rest of the world.

Comment: http://landcover.usgs.gov/glcc/download.php

Comment: If it's open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find Global Land Cover 2000 dataset produced by JRC (an EU organization)
https://forobs.jrc.ec.europa.eu/products/glc2000/products.php

Answer (score 2):

Maybe check the USGS Land Cover Institute (LCI)

http://landcover.usgs.gov/landcoverdata.php

Answer (score 1):

There is also another dataset with resolution 30 m

http://www.globallandcover.com/